# All the Model properties are binded as string and it throws "The value XX is not valid" in ModelState validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devexpress-mvc

I am getting value XX is not valid. But I am binding the correct datatype to the Model and I am still getting this error. Please find the error in [image]. My controller is considering all datatype besides string to be not valid. Even the StartData and EndDate is throwing the same exception though I am binding the correct datatype.

I am not sure am I missing anything here. The worse part here is if I try to implement same (file) in another sample project it is working fine.

Following is my Model

```
public class Dept_User_Link
    {
        public Dept_User_Link()
        {
            StartDate = DateTime.Now;
            EndDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private List<Dept_User_Link> deptUserLink = new List<Dept_User_Link>();
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int DeptID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Guid Dummy { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DateRange(StartDateEditFieldName = "StartDate")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

}

and following is my controller

```
      public ActionResult GridVwPartial()
            {
                var model = new Dept_User_Link().GetDeptUsersLink();
                ViewData["Departments"] = new Department().GetDepartments().Select(x => new { DeptID = x.ID, Name = x.Name }).ToList();
                ViewData["Users"] = new Users().GetUsers().Select(x => new { UserID = x.ID, Name = x.Name }).ToList();
                ViewData["GuidVals"] = new GuidVal().GuidValData();
                return PartialView("GridVwPartial", model);
            }

  public ActionResult AddNew(Dept_User_Link data) {
            // Add 'data' values to the underlying datasource
            // ...

            var model = new Dept_User_Link().GetDeptUsersLink();
            ViewData["Departments"] = new Department().GetDepartments().Select(x => new { DeptID = x.ID, Name = x.Name }).ToList();
            ViewData["Users"] = new Users().GetUsers().Select(x => new { UserID = x.ID, Name = x.Name }).ToList();

            return GridVwPartial();
        }
```

and following is my View

```
@using ROCKtree.CCTVWeb.Models
@model IList<Dept_User_Link>
@{


    Html.DevExpress().GridView<Dept_User_Link>(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "cascadingExample";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Grid", Action = "GridVwPartial" };
        settings.SettingsEditing.AddNewRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Grid", Action = "AddNew" };
        settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ShowNewButtonInHeader = true;
        settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.EditForm;
        settings.KeyFieldName = "ID";

        settings.Columns.Add(m => m.DeptID, column =>
        {
            column.EditorProperties().ComboBox(x =>
            {
                x.TextField = "Name";
                x.ValueField = "DeptID";
                x.DataSource = ViewData["Departments"];
                x.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedDeptChanges";
                x.ValidationSettings.CausesValidation = true;
                //x.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "";
            });
        });

        settings.Columns.Add(m => m.UserID, column =>
        {
            column.EditorProperties().ComboBox(x =>
            {
                x.TextField = "Name";
                x.ValueField = "UserID";
                //x.DataSource = ViewData["Users"];
                x.LoadDropDownOnDemand = true;
                x.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Grid", Action = "UserCallback" };
                x.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "UserComboBox_BeginCallback";
                // x.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "";

            });

        });

        settings.Columns.Add(m => m.Dummy, column =>
        {
            column.EditorProperties().ComboBox(cmb =>
            {
                cmb.TextField = "Name";
                cmb.ValueField = "ID";
                cmb.DataSource = ViewData["GuidVals"];
            });
        });


        settings.Columns.Add(m => m.StartDate, column =>
        {
            column.EditorProperties().DateEdit(clm =>
            {
                clm.TimeSectionProperties.Visible = true;
                clm.DisplayFormatString = "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm";
                clm.DisplayFormatInEditMode = true;
                clm.TimeSectionProperties.TimeEditProperties.EditFormatString = "HH";
                clm.TimeSectionProperties.TimeEditProperties.EditFormat = EditFormat.Custom;
                clm.UseMaskBehavior = true;
                clm.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithTooltip;
                clm.ValidationSettings.Display = Display.Dynamic;
                clm.ValidationSettings.CausesValidation = true;
                clm.ValidationSettings.SetFocusOnError = true;
            });
            //column.SetEditItemTemplateContent(c =>
            //{
            //    ViewContext.Writer.Write("<div class='form-group'><div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'><input type='text' class=\"form-control\" /><span class=\"input-group-addon\">");
            //    ViewContext.Writer.Write("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-calendar\"></span></span></div></div>");
            //});
        });


        settings.Columns.Add(m => m.EndDate, column =>
        {
            column.EditorProperties().DateEdit(clm =>
            {
                clm.TimeSectionProperties.Visible = true;
                clm.DisplayFormatString = "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm";
                clm.DisplayFormatInEditMode = true;
                clm.TimeSectionProperties.TimeEditProperties.EditFormatString = "HH";
                clm.TimeSectionProperties.TimeEditProperties.EditFormat = EditFormat.Custom;
                clm.UseMaskBehavior = true;
                clm.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithTooltip;
                clm.ValidationSettings.Display = Display.Dynamic;
                clm.ValidationSettings.CausesValidation = true;
                clm.ValidationSettings.SetFocusOnError = true;
            });
            //column.SetEditItemTemplateContent(c =>
            //{
            //    ViewContext.Writer.Write("<div class='form-group'><div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'><input type='text' class=\"form-control\" /><span class=\"input-group-addon\">");
            //    ViewContext.Writer.Write("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-calendar\"></span></span></div></div>");
            //});
        });
    }).Bind(Model).GetHtml();
}
```

Data for the Dummy Property

```
   public IList<GuidVal> GuidValData()
            {
                if (guidVal == null || guidVal.Count() == 0)
                {
                    //List<Department> deptList = new List<Department>();
                    List<string> deptValues = File.ReadLines(path).ToList();

                    foreach (string data in deptValues)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
                        {
                            string[] str = data.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None);
                            GuidVal deptLnk = new GuidVal();
                            deptLnk.ID = Guid.Parse(str[0]);
                            deptLnk.Name = str[1];
                            this.guidVal.Add(deptLnk);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return guidVal;

            }
```

Comment: Just  a try .. change type from guid to string of Dummy ..does it still not work?

Comment: When I change the type from Guid to string it works fine. But I am looking for the cause of this issue..

Comment: Ehsan, Dummy is Guid property. I am getting the the error for that property only.

Comment: Please show the implementation of `GuidVal.GuidValData()`, it may produce incorrect Guid-strings. And on a separate note: I think it is strange that your ViewModel classes have those `Get...()` methods - and even stranger, they exist at instance-level. That should not be in there, it would be much better to create a DataLayer or DataProvider class for that.

Comment: This is a sample project that I have created to use. I have just extracted the data from a text file and pass the values in the controller

Comment: the cause of the issue is that the guid that you're sending to the back end is not a valid Guid ...maybe you've to set the length of the Guid on the poperty required of back end

Comment: Fedrico, I dont think so. As the value in ModelState error value, the value seems to be correct and also even the Start Date and End Date also has the same issue (where in the datatype is DateTime)